# How to push <DIVS> together, vertically?

Tags: html

I've been looking for a solution for this, for a long time now.
How can I vertically push divs together (see attached image).

It's been suggested to use specific CSS coding, but that is no good in this case as the div height is not set - it changes depending on the content being loaded.

[image: push divs together vertically]

------------------Added information ------------------

As requested, this is the code the populates the divs using content from a database. The divs simply need to be pushed up as shown in the attached image.

```
<?php 

require_once('../scripts/include.php');
$who = 65; //temp value to be deleted

            $result = mysql_query(
            "SELECT 

            tbl_status.id as statID, 
            tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
            tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
            tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
            tbl_status.date as statDATE,

            tbl_users.id as usrID, 
            tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
            tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,

            tbl_photos.profile as photosPROFILE,
            tbl_photos.photo_link as photoLINK,
            tbl_photos.default_photo as photoDEFAULT 

            FROM tbl_status 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id

            LEFT JOIN tbl_photos ON tbl_photos.profile = tbl_users.id 
            WHERE tbl_status.deleted = '0' AND tbl_photos.default_photo IS NULL OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1'
            ORDER BY tbl_status.date desc
            LIMIT 24

            ");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {          

                    $sampleText = $row['statSTATUS'];
                    $pattern = '/#[a-zA-Z0-9]*/';
                    $replacement = '<a href="../search/term.php?$0" class="hashSearch">$0</a>';
                    $updatedText = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement ,$sampleText);

                    echo'
                    <div class="statusCont" style="width:150px;">

                        <div class="statusUsr">' . $row['usrLOCATION'] . '</div>
                        <div class="statusTxt"><p>' . $updatedText . '</p></div>
                        <div class="statBackground" style="background-image:url(../assets/uploads/resized_' . $row['photoLINK'] .');
                        background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%;width:150px; height:50px; opacity:1;"></div>

                    </div><!-- ends .statusCont -->
                    ';}

    ?>
```

Comment: can you supply your part of html for reference? because it may be your html's problem

Comment: Well, I'm currently filling various DIVs with text content from a database in a while-loop. The content amount is different in each DIV so looks like the attached image.
The HTML code is pretty much <div style="float:left; width:150px">sample</div>

Comment: I have updated my question to include code

Answer (score 0):

Do 3 columns :

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mHgCc)

HTML

```
<div id="col1" class="col">
    <div id="rand1"></div>
    <div id="rand2"></div>
</div>

<div id="col2" class="col">
    <div id="rand3"></div>
    <div id="rand4"></div>
</div>

<div id="col3" class="col">
    <div id="rand5"></div>
    <div id="rand6"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px
}

#rand1 
{
    height:90px;
    background: pink; 
}

#rand2 
{
    height:100px;
    background: green; 
}

#rand3 
{
    height:200px;
    background: grey; 
}

#rand4
{
    height:200px;
    background: red;  
}

#rand5 
{
    height:300px;
    background: green; 
}

#rand6 
{
    height:150px;
    background: red;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
     $i=1;
     $sampleText = array();
     $pattern = array();
     $replacement = array();
     $updatedText = array();
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                      {          
    
                        $sampleText[$i] = $row['statSTATUS'];
                        $pattern[$i] = '/#[a-zA-Z0-9]*/';
                        $replacement[$i] = '<a href="../search/term.php?$0" class="hashSearch">$0</a>';
                        $updatedText[$i] = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement ,$sampleText[$i]);
    
    
               $Myvar[$i] ='<div class="statusCont" style="width:150px;">
    
                            <div class="statusUsr">' . $row['usrLOCATION'] . '</div>
                            <div class="statusTxt"><p>' . $updatedText[$i] . '</p></div>
                            <div class="statBackground" style="background-image:url(../assets/uploads/resized_' . $row['photoLINK'] .');
                            background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%;width:150px; height:50px; opacity:1;"></div>
                        </div>';                    
                $i++;                      
                       }
    $col1=1;
$col2=2;
$col3=3;
$i=$i-1;
//column2
echo '<div  class="col">';
        while($col1<=$i) {

                echo $Myvar[$col1] ;           

            $col1=$col1+3;     

        }
 echo '</div>';  
 //column2
 echo '<div  class="col">';
        while($col2<=$i) {

                echo $Myvar[$col2]  ;          

            $col2=$col2+3;     

        }
 echo '</div>'; 
 //column 3
 echo '<div  class="col">';
        while($col3<=$i) {

                echo $Myvar[$col3]  ;          

            $col3=$col3+3;   
        }
 echo '</div>';  

print_r ($Myvar); 

                    ?>
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but would cause the first 3 results to be placed under one-another in column 1, when ideally they should be the first top 3 results from left to right.

Comment: You call your div with php ? Plz past your view.

Comment: i updated my answer with php code. And edit php, some errors :s

Comment: It's very hard to debug Php, when i cannot test ^^'

Comment: The divs are there, but no content is being placed into them

Comment: Can u put the code generated on pastie ? i hab forgot ; for the echo, is maybe the problem :p

Comment: <body>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
</body>

Comment: print_r($Myvar) ; echos all information out, but it does not place divs into columns (i have included your CSS code, also)

Comment: My gad xd, my bad, is a bad condition for the while :s $col<=$i and not >= :s

Comment: That DOES put the content into 3 columns, but the same content spans all 3 columns. result 1 for example appears in column 1, 2 and 3. Then result 2 appears in column 1, 2 and 3 and so on..

Comment: [My wamp test](http://pastie.org/8441313#1) , i test with this code and it's work. Compare and this script will work (i don t put many $var cause i don't have.)

Comment: I'm going to have a look at it again tomorrow

Comment: OK, so... i have coped in all your coding and currently no content is being placed into each column. But 3 columns ARE being output.

Comment: give me the print_r($result); in the pastie. i will can read with real var. Do not get upset, I try to help you = ')

Comment: That's what is being output... unless you want all my code? (I'm also using 4 columns, not 3)

Comment: Oo, don't understand. i just want the print_r($result); example : $result = array ( ...);.with lorem ipsum in content, is not a problem. I just want use your while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) and without "$result" i can use it.

Comment: just add print_r($result); in your code (under your "$result=mysql_query(...);"). and refresh your chrome. Give me this result...

Comment: AGHHHHHH, It doesnt work. i might just abandon this.

Comment: as you want [place ur print_r](http://pastie.org/private/qungqab5ztqea5hb2xtsg). [look php faq](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: That puts this: Resource id #11

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea which I think you can implement in your site with the 3-column idea.

How about using the MOD `%` of the total posts displayed on your page.

Since you have 3 columns, the first post will be in the first column. If a second post post out, the first one will display on the second column, and etc.

Let the total number of post displayed on the page be `$total`.
And let the current number be `$current`.

```
$total; // the total divs will be displaying in the page

for ($current = 1; $currrent < $total+1; $current++)
{
    if($current % 3 == 1)
    {
        //the code php or javascript to display <div> in column 1
    }
    else if($current % 3 == 2)
    {
        //the code php or javascript to display <div> in column 2
    }
    else if($current % 3 == 0)
    {
        //the code php or javascript to display <div> in column 3
    }
}
```

Please forgive me if I made mistakes in the code but you get the idea.